# Error when install GDAL

Tags: python

I'm trying to install GDAL for python 3.6.9 under Ubuntu 18.04 following the way at: https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/
I tried these two ways: 'easy_install' '''sudo easy_install GDAL''' and the 'setup.py' '''python setup.py build &&python setup.py install'''.

But they're all failed. Here is the information back to me when I use '''sudo easy_install GDAL''':

extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3209:9: error: ‘GDALExtendedDataTypeHS’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘GDALFindDataType’?
typedef GDALExtendedDataTypeHS GDALExtendedDataTypeHS;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
GDALFindDataType

...

extensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp:5771:51: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘*’ token
extensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp:5771:53: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
arg8 = reinterpret_cast< GDALExtendedDataTypeHS * >(argp8);
^
extensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp:5771:61: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
arg8 = reinterpret_cast< GDALExtendedDataTypeHS * >(argp8);
^

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

How can I install the GDAL properly?

Comment: Please do not invent your own Markdown!

Answer (score 1):

You can install GDAL with Python binding from the [repository using](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gdal+python&searchon=names):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal python-gdal libgdal-dev
```

Comment: Thaks, this works for me in some extent.